# Serverless(aws-node): Call a function from a different file returns internal server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

So I have this following functions on my `serverless.yml`

```
functions:
getEstimate:
handler: handler.getEstimate
events:
  - http:
      path: /get-quotation
      method: get

getQuotation: 
handler: lalamove/index.getQuotation
events:
  - http:
      path: /lalamove-get-quote
      method: get
```

and I have this code in `handler.js` that calls getQuotation() function from lalamove/index.getQuotation.

```
'use strict';
 var lalamove = require("./lalamove/index.js");


 module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
   lalamove.getQuotation();
 };
```

after serverless deploy, and I look run the getEstimate endpoint I get `{"message": "Internal server error"}`
but if I try to run getQuotation, I get `{"message":"hermbs"}` which should be printed too when I run getEstimate.

this is my `index.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports.getQuotation = (data, context, callback) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: "hermbs",
        }),
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: You need to pass the function parameters which in your case for getQuotation are data, context and callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this one out:

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.body);

   lalamove.getQuotation(data ,context, function(err, data){
     callback(null,data)
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a best practice to call another lambda function like this. 
I'd suggest to extract the code you need in a third "shared/util" module and have both modules import the functions they need from the third module